# Выход за пределы массива в cuda

Tags: c++, c, opencv, cuda

Начинаю осваивать `cuda` и при работе с блоками и нитями задался вопросом что происходит в случае выхода за пределы массива. Тобишь, допустим, у нас есть изобаржение размером 257х257 - важно чтобы оно не было кратно числу потоков. Количество потоков тоже запишем двумерным: 16х16. Таким образом если мы укажем блок размером 16x16 (целочисленное деление, помните?), то обработается у нас не все изображение (это я даже не беру в расчет непрвильную индексацию). Таким образом нам нужно взять размер блока больше 17х17. Раз так, то встает вопрос: какого размера должен быть массив, выделяем на `GPU`? Так как я знаю что происходит при выходе за пределы массива на `CPU`, то я выделил больше памяти, нежели исходное изображение (чтобы исключить подобную ошибку). Так вот: следует ли так делать, или подобного выхода не произойдет если выделить памяти ровно столько, сколько занимает изображение? Вторую половину вопроса я бы не задавал, если бы не видел, как при попытке скопировать данные из `CPU` to `GPU` функция `cudaMemcpy` не выдала ошибку (invalid argument) из-за того, что я выделил массив меньше, чем собираюсь копировать (а это означает, что, в отличии от `CPU`, где-то сохраняется количество выделенной памяти.

Вот код (да, это альфа блендинг двух изображений):

```
// first is 3chanel image, second - 4 chanel image
__global__ void blend(unsigned char *first, unsigned char *second) {
  int x      = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  int y      = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
  int width  = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
  int offset = x + y * width;

  unsigned char *curPixelFirst  = first + offset * 3;
  unsigned char *curPixelSecond = second + offset * 4;

  if (curPixelSecond[3]) {
    float beta       = curPixelSecond[3] / 255.;
    curPixelFirst[0] = curPixelFirst[0] * (1 - beta) + curPixelSecond[0] * beta;
    curPixelFirst[1] = curPixelFirst[1] * (1 - beta) + curPixelSecond[1] * beta;
    curPixelFirst[2] = curPixelFirst[2] * (1 - beta) + curPixelSecond[2] * beta;
  }
}

void blending(cv::Mat &first, const cv::Mat &second) {
  assert(first.size == second.size);
  assert(first.elemSize() == 3);
  assert(second.elemSize() == 4);
  assert(first.elemSize1() == 1);
  assert(second.elemSize1() == 1);

  CHECK_CUDA_DEVICE();

  dim3 threads{16, 16};
  dim3 blocks{(unsigned)(first.cols + threads.x - 1) / threads.x, (unsigned)(first.rows + threads.y - 1) / threads.y};

  unsigned char *firstImageCuda  = nullptr;
  unsigned char *secondImageCuda = nullptr;

  size_t sizeOfFirst  = first.total() * first.elemSize();
  size_t sizeOfSecond = second.total() * second.elemSize();
  // here i get more memory, because result (cols / t) can have not integral part
  size_t allocSize = blocks.x * threads.x * blocks.y * threads.y;
  CUDA_THROW_IF(cudaMalloc(&firstImageCuda, allocSize * first.elemSize()));
  CUDA_THROW_IF(cudaMalloc(&secondImageCuda, allocSize * second.elemSize()));

  CUDA_THROW_IF(cudaMemcpy(firstImageCuda, first.data, sizeOfFirst, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
  CUDA_THROW_IF(cudaMemcpy(secondImageCuda, second.data, sizeOfSecond, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

  blend<<<blocks, threads>>>(firstImageCuda, secondImageCuda);

  CUDA_THROW_IF(cudaMemcpy(first.data, firstImageCuda, sizeOfFirst, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
  CUDA_THROW_IF(cudaMemcpy(second.data, secondImageCuda, sizeOfSecond, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

  cudaFree(firstImageCuda);
  cudaFree(secondImageCuda);
}
```

`CUDA_THROW_IF` просто бросает исключение в случае ошибки

Comment: Какой-то мутный вопрос. При выходе за пределы массива естественно ничего хорошего не произойдет. Если входные данные не совсем подходят по габаритам, то они либо дополняются до нужного размера путем добавления пустого места ака padding, либо края обрабатываются отдельно. Ничего хитрого. А в такой задаче, как в примере, разбивать на квадратные блоки не имеет смысла. Проще разбить по строкам.

Comment: @VTT понятно, что выход за пределы чреват проблемами, я не об этом спрашивал, а о том: будет ли он (так как я полагаю, что в отличии от CPU для GPU где-то хранится размер выделенной памяти, а раз так, то зачем запускать блоки, который выходят за пределы - но это лишь мои догадки)? По поводу дополнения - так я и сделал в коде